# phpBB - display a public message when the whole board is private

Tags: forum, phpbb

In my installation all discussion forums/boards are private and can only be seen after a user registers and admin approves their membership.  This is working.

When a user first comes to the main phpBB page and they're not logged in, they can see very little except for the login and registration functions.

Now I'm trying to configure phpBB to display a Read Me posting that is available to general public before registration or login.

The problem is that I'd have to create a whole "public" forum and it would likely contain only one topic thread called "Read Me".  The users would have to click into the public forum and then click again to get into the Topic called "Read Me".

Is it possible to have a Topic thread outside of a forum?

If not, is there another, better, way to achieve this?  I just want to display a message, maybe a few short paragraphs to the public, explaining the purpose of the Forum and that they must register and wait for approval in order to gain additional access.

I'm not seeing anything like this in the ACP.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

You could move your forum to a sub folded or sub-domain. With this method you'll be able to place your main message on your home page. Along with the ability to create any other pages needed.

Another method is to add a static message into the header of the login page and use the built in functions of phpBB to display the message only to users who are not logged in.

Comment: Actually, phpBB is already in a sub-folder, so landing people on another page with the message would work.  However, the way my navigation is constructed, even people who are logged in would still have to click through this page.  So I like your second idea better.  I'll probably modify the login page and toggle the message based on user login status.

Comment: Like WordPress i'm sure that you can include a few PHP files into your main index file at the top level allowing you to use phpBB functions outside it's folder. Then you can check if people landing on your home page are logged in or on and display messages accordingly.